# Splitting Dice Pool between actions with and without dice roll

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages

In Vampire: Dark Ages 1st edition, I'm a little bit confused by the rules for splitting the dice pool in situations where you want to use multiple actions and one of the actions does not require rolling dice.

Let's say that I'm a Ravnos and I want to use Ignis Fatuus to create an illusion *and* make an attack with a sword at the same turn. The first action doesn't require a dice roll; just spending 1 point of Willpower. The second action requires a dice roll. But what would happen? Could I just assign 1 die to "use" my Discipline (which I will not roll dice for, but use Willpower instead) and then use the rest of my pool to attack?

Comment: Can you specify which edition of Dark Ages you're using? The multiple action rules differ between them.

Comment: The first edition, I believe. But it will be helpful if you post both scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first edition (**Vampire: the Dark Ages**), that's a valid use of the rules. In later editions, you'd penalize the sword swing by a greater degree, but in this version, you can do as you describe. In fact, there's no statement in the rules that you even need to allot a single die to the Chimerstry action. This may be why this rule changed in later versions of the game.